# List items from blob container C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

Need Help,

Trying to get a list for items stored in blob-container however unable to understand why it times-out.

The error that I get is: -

> ReadTimeout    '((System.IO.Stream)(swa.BaseStream)).ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'    int {System.InvalidOperationException}

Detail error message:

[image]

Used the code from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs

so as on below code - resultSegment gets Result count = 2327 but on listblob.txt only exports - 2279 then it timesout

```
namespace listblob
{
    class Program
    {

         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containername");

            ListBlobsSegmentedInFlatListing(container).Wait();
        }

        async public static Task ListBlobsSegmentedInFlatListing(CloudBlobContainer container)
        {
            int i = 0;
            BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
            BlobResultSegment resultSegment = null;
            string patha = @"C:\listblob.txt";
            StreamWriter swa = File.CreateText(patha);

            do
            {
                resultSegment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync("", true, BlobListingDetails.All, 10, continuationToken, null, null);
                if (resultSegment.Results.Count<IListBlobItem>() > 0) //{ Console.WriteLine("Page {0}:", ++i); }
                foreach (var blobItem in resultSegment.Results)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", blobItem.StorageUri.PrimaryUri);
                    swa.WriteLine(blobItem.Uri.Segments[2]);
                }
.
                continuationToken = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;
            }
            while (continuationToken != null);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCtiD.jpg

Comment: I tried running your code and there is no issues and its working fine. Can you try to change the path of the file from `Drive c` to someother drive and check? and post the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply Thennarasan. i tried as per you suggestion but had no change on result.

However i Copied all to String List and got the expected result.

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
list.Add(blobItem.Uri.Segments[2]);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("SavedLists.txt", list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> blobNames = list.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
```

try using this way

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion